# List<string> Item which contains this

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I have a list stored as a text file, stored as such

```
Id;name;function
```

I have a function that takes the text file and reads it in line by line, each line of text is a new item in a List. Achieved by doing the fallowing.

```
List<String> list
list.add(line);
```

What I am trying to do is see if some Id such as "0x0640e331" is in the list. And if it is get everything on the line of text that that Id is found. So the fallowing would happen,

```
0x0604f552;name0;function
0x0640e331;name1;function
0x0342t521;name2;function
```

Searching for 0x0640e331 would return, 0x0640e331;name1;function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should implement HashMap<String,String> to achieve this. With list, retrieval performance that you will achieve will be lesser as compared to HashMap.
If you want to do it with list, you could iterate and check for existence of the key using `tokenizer` or `String#startsWith`. Order will be equal to O(n) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [`startsWith` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) like this ...

```
ArrayList<String> queryResult = new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "0x0640e331";
for(String line : list) {
  if(line.startsWith(query)) {
     queryResult.add(line);
  }
}
return queryResult;
```

This basically checks if a given line in the array-list starts with your `query` string. If there is more than one line simply add it in another ArrayList and return that as the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Map<String,List>
```

Store your id as key in the Map and retrieve the values on the key

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map instead of a list.  See the sample program given below

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TextProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String lineArray[] = { "0x0604f552;name0;function",
                "0x0640e331;name1;function", "0x0342t521;name2;function" };
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = null;
        for (String string : lineArray) {

            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string, ";");
            map.put(tokenizer.nextToken(), string);
        }
        System.out.println(map.get("0x0640e331"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use `Map<String,String>` for each element in the list get the string and store it in the map

**pseudocode:**

```
for(String item : list) {

String keyName= //use substring to get the id value from the string variable 'item'

map.put(keyName,item);
}
System.out.println(map.get("0x0640e331"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large file so you dont want to read it all and lines in your files are sorted by id, you can implement your own [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm using RandomAccessFile. To read line in the random position, you first select position, and then read forward and backward until a new line symbol.